# Implementing findpeaks in for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have written the following code for calculating the local maximum and its location in for loop but I get an error that I have a dimension mismatch.  What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
   for col = 1:3000;
         c1(:,col)=xc(2:end,col);
% matrix xc is my matrix, it could be any random 2d matrix, and for each column i want to implement the findpeaks function

         [cmax(:,col),locs(:,col)]=findpeaks(c1(:,col));

    end
```

Comment: Give the full error message. It identifies the command that causes the error.

Comment: the error message is : "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch".

Comment: i understand why i get the error , it's because the number of peaks in each column is changing so the only solution i suppose is to use cells

Comment: @user_dsp - Correct.   Consider adding in an answer that explains this, or delete your question as you have solved your problem.... or, I can add an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findpeaks` is most likely giving you a **different** number of detected peaks and locations for each invocation that is made to the function.  Because you're trying to slice into a matrix which is not ragged (MATLAB does not support ragged matrices), you will get a dimension mismatch.

A solution would perhaps be to use cell arrays instead:

```
%// Declare cell arrays here
cmax = cell(3000,1);
locs = cell(3000,1);
for col = 1:3000;
     c1(:,col)=xc(2:end,col);
     %// Change
     [cmax{col},locs{col}]=findpeaks(c1(:,col));
end
```

However, if you don't like the use of cell arrays, what you would do is create a matrix of `NaN` values and only populate for up to as many peaks as you have detected per result and keeping the rest of the entries as `NaN`.... so something like this:

```
%// Declare cmax and locs to be an array of nans
cmax = nan(size(xc));
locs = nan(size(xc));
for col = 1:3000;
     c1(:,col)=xc(2:end,col);
     %// Change
     [c,l]=findpeaks(c1(:,col));
     %// Determine total number of peaks and locations
     N = numel(c);

     %// Populate each column up to this point
     cmax(1:N,:) = c;
     locs(1:N,:) = l;
end
```